# Why doesn't my root view's height take account of its navigation bar?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I was under the impression that a UINavigationController's navigation bar would always push down the child view's height, such that the child view's origin was at the bottom of the title bar.

But when I present a view controller like this ...

```
MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
viewController.title = @"My View Controller";
viewController.navigationItem.prompt = @"My Prompt";
viewController.delegate = self;

[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
[navigationController release]; [viewController release];
```

... and then check `self.view.frame.size.height` with an NSLog in `viewDidLoad`, it reports that my view is 460px high. Shouldn't it subtracting the height of my title & prompt?

Comment: Have you logged `self.view.frame.size.height` in `viewWillAppear` as well? Off the top of my head, the typical behavior is for the vc to resize itself only when it's pushed into view.

Comment: @lxt you're absolutely right! Please re-write that in an answer so I can mark it as correct :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Have rewritten below.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So, as requested:

When you call `viewDidLoad` the view controller hasn't been pushed onto the screen yet. So when you get the frame size from within that method it will report its' default (typically, 320x480 for an iPhone app).

The view then autoresizes to take into account the navigation bar. So when you check the frame size in `viewWillAppear` it will now be correct. Typically this isn't a problem for iPhone apps. For iPad apps, where you have multiple orientations, it can be a bit of a pain!

There are a few exceptions to this - for example, when using NIBs.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you are referring to the **wrong** `self` here.
When `self` refers to the `MyViewController` instance you will probably have an height of 460 - 44 pixels (standard `UIToolbar` height), but if `self` refers to a parent view controller (e.g. the navigation view controller itself) you'll see the standard view height (e.g. 460px).

You can check this by calling `self.view.frame.size.height` inside the instance of `MyViewController`, e.g. when the view has finished loading (`viewWillAppear:` method), and so has already been resized by its navigation controller.

If you call `self.view.frame.size.height` from the `viewDidLoad` method, the view probably has still not been resized by its parent controller.

Please try again and let me know if this fixes your problem.

Comment: I'm a little confused - wouldn't the "self" be the same, whether it was in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`? It does indeed make a difference (it works as I expected in `viewWillAppear`), but I suspect that is because the view has not yet been resized in `viewDidLoad`, as lxt suggests above.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the `self` is the same in those two methods, I thought you were calling it from somewhere else. The `viewWillAppear:` gets called once the view has been drawn, so already resized to the correct dimensions. Just updated the answer.