# Get Actual Size of a UIView/MapKit View

Tags: ios, uiview, mkmapview

How do I get the actual height of a MKMapView (not the one specified in Interface builder).

Here's my example. I created a view in interface builder containing a map, referenced as **IBOutlet MKMapView* worldmap**.

[image]

The actual size of this view (see image, right) is different than the one specified in Interface Builder (see image, left) because I also add a navigation bar (by code) and the height of the map/view changes according to the device screen (4 or 3,5").

However when I use ...

```
worldmap.frame.size.height
```

... I always get the size set in Interface Builder not the adapted *real* one.

How do I get the actual size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018818/why-doesnt-my-root-views-height-take-account-of-its-navigation-bar).
I tried to get the height in the **viewDidLoad** function which gets called before the navigation bar is added. The solution is to get the frame height in the **viewWillAppear** function instead.